# Remove duplicate lines in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following example format:

```
ID Name 
1  NULL
1  NULL
2  HELLO 
3  NULL
3  BYE
```

My goal is to remove repeated lines with same IDS, but with restrictions. 
According to the example,  I need to remove a row with ID-1, and the row with ID-3 and with no value (NULL).

I would stick with the table:

```
ID Name 
1  NULL
2  HELLO 
3  BYE
```

How can I do this in sql server? thank you

Comment: Have a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Comment: Do you want to just select the result, or actually remove the rows from the existing table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just *select* the data, you can use a simple CTE (common table expression);

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name DESC) rn
  FROM myTable
)
SELECT id,name FROM cte WHERE rn=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb4c3/8).

If you mean to **delete the duplicates from the table** and not just select the data without updating anything, you could use the same CTE;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name DESC) rn
  FROM myTable
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn<>1;
```

[Another SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb4c3/5), and remember to always back up your data before running destructive SQL statements from random people on the Internet.